# Bad idea to have two class opening the same file?

Tags: python, file

I have two classes in my Python program and one of them is a thread. Is it a bad idea to have both classes open the same log file and write to it?

Is there any good approach to write to the same log file for two classes which are running at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

This is a classical concurrency issue. You need to ensure that you exactly control what is happening. Regarding log files, the easiest solution might be to have a queue collecting log messages from various places (from different threads or even processes) and then have **one** entity that pops messages from that queue and writes them to the log file. This way, at least single messages stay self-contained.

The operating system does not prevent message mix up if you write to the file from different unsynchronized entities. Hence, if you do not explicitly control what should happen in which order, you might end up with corrupted messages in that file, even if things *seem* to work most of the time.

Comment: thanks thats a a very interesting approeach, which class would own the Queue ? lets say I have classA and classB ...if classA has self.myQ,  how would call B have access to it?

Comment: The `threading` as well as the `multiprocessing` modules in Python provide simple queues. No class would 'own' such a queue. You would **share** one queue object among e.g. a couple of threads (the required synchronization/locking is done internally by the Python module, you don't have to worry about this). You can then simply put Python objects, such as strings, into that queue from any thread. Only in one thread you pop these objects (strings in this case) and write them to disk.

Comment: that seems to be really interesting, do you know any example of sharing a queue object between two classes, that I can look at ?

Comment: You do not share between classes (make sure to get the difference between class and instance). You could say that you share a queue between objects. Or even more simple, you can use the same queue object in different "places" of your program. Doing so, you can transmit information between different "places" of your program. These places could be different threads. Have a look at the bottom of the page http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue -- there is a simple example of how to share one queue object among threads and use it as a very simple synchronization primitive.

Answer (score 1):

Use the python [logging module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html). It handles the gory details for you.

Comment: @Jan-Philip Gehrcke - the question is about classes and threads, not multiprocessing.

Comment: I would say the question is about concepts :) I agree, in case of threading the `logging` module entirely solves the issue transparently to the user, which is great. I wanted to provide some insight about the issue itself and its general solution.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you control which class is reading and writing from a file and ensure that only one of them can write to it at a time you should be fine and every time you switch you reread the file.

Look into using [lock](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) to ensure that both classes are not accessing the file at the same time.